# How to share gRPC proto data between client and server

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, grpc

I just started learning gRPC and I got an issue with [proto files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/basics?view=aspnetcore-3.0), as I understand these files define the model of incoming-outgoing data.

On the server side everything is OK. The server compiles and runs fine, but the client side does not recognize proto files from the server. Using Visual Studio 2019, it suggest to add the whole server as a reference.

At this point I believed I went too far. Looking for a solution, I read that I need to add it as a Service Reference, but Visual Studio 2019 only offers WCF and Azure service. Do I need to copy paste proto files from the server to the client since looking on other "tutorials" I noticed that proto files copy pasted to client, client and server are [.NET Core 3.0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Core#History) and [ASP.NET Core 3.0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET_Core#Release_history).

Comment: See following : https://www.grpc.io/docs/tutorials/basic/csharp/

Comment: I did read "...MSBuild to provide automatic C# code generation from .proto files, which gives much better developer experience by running the right commands for you as part of the build.", but how to share proto files BETWEEN client and server PS. "Next we need to generate the gRPC client and server interfaces from our .proto service definition." does that mean I have create third project which contains definitions of all proto data?

Comment: No.  You could one project reference the other project, or you could have a class project that both project reference.  I do not think you want to duplicate the same code in two different projects.

Comment: Indeed I dont want, I hoped that I could remotely read class from server and use as remote class on client side

Comment: No reason you couldn't have class on a shared Network Drive so it could be used in both locations.

Answer (score 13):

Go to your client app

- right click on "Dependencies" > "Add Connected Service"
- click "Service References" tab
- choose "Add new gRPC service reference"

In a popup window specify path to .proto file and choose type of class to be generated - "Client".
Now you will have one .proto file for two projects.

This is instruction for Visual Studio 2019.

Comment: I can't see anything like "Add new gRPC service reference". Does it require any extra plugins?

Comment: No special plugins required. May be your case is ASP.NET Core gRPC and it has additional requirements for being used with Azure App Service or IIS. More here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/basics?view=aspnetcore-3.0

Answer (score 2):

Another thing to consider is using [Code-First gRPC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/code-first) approach.

In this fashion, you write the gRPC messages and services in C# contracts like so:

```cs
[DataContract]
public class HelloReply
{
    [DataMember(Order = 1)]
    public string Message { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class HelloRequest
{
    [DataMember(Order = 1)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

[ServiceContract]
public interface IGreeterService
{
    [OperationContract]
    Task<HelloReply> SayHelloAsync(HelloRequest request,
        CallContext context = default);
}
```

When you know you will be using both your server and client in C#, you can skip using proto altogether.

You can then use [protobuf-net.Grpc](https://github.com/protobuf-net/protobuf-net.Grpc) to generate the *.proto* files should you need them for external systems.