# Difference between service reference and service dependency

Tags: c#, grpc, visual-studio-2022

This is a follow up question to this one:

[How to share gRPC proto data between client and server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57441513/how-to-share-grpc-proto-data-between-client-and-server)

I got a gRPC service with a proto in a repo. In the same repo (but a different sln) I got an SDK (client) to access this service which is supposed to be published as a nuget. Both service and client are implemented using C# and .NET 6.

What I'm trying to do is have the SDK use the same proto file as defined in the service. The accepted answer to the linked question says I should add a service dependency of the grpc service to the SDK. When tried adding the service, I was prompted with a choice between adding a service dependency or a service reference (OpenAPI, gRPC, WCF).

I'm guessing by the choices that I need to add a reference and not a dependency, but still - what is the difference between them? And am I correct that I need to choose the reference and not the dependency?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly, but if you want to use the protos and generated code behind files in a different project than where they are defined (in this case your service), you need to add a reference to the protos in that project AND add the necessary NuGet packages which contain the protoc compiler to generate the code-behind files in that project, which is in your case the Client / SDK. This does not seemed to be explained very well in the SO post you linked, I think that answer could be improved...